# In python project(with page object) conftest file doesn't get driver from pages

Tags: python, selenium, constructor, pageobjects

I try to create the project with page object(python 3.9) and my conftest.py file doesn't receive any driver from its pages.
Any page has _*init* constructors,but in the conftest.py file we can see that no driver is given.
I will be glad if you have any conclusions...

Functions of conftest.py

```
import time

import pytest as pytest
from selenium import webdriver

from src.pom import settings
from src.pom.pages.BasePage import BasePage
from src.pom.pages.LoginPage import LoginPage

# from pytest_lazyfixture import lazy_fixture

driver = None


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    # parser.addoption("--browser", action="store", default="chrome")
    parser.addoption("--browser", action="store", default=settings.browser)
    parser.addoption("--env", action="store", default=settings.env)


@pytest.fixture()
# @lazy_fixture
def getBrowser(request):
    _browser = request.config.getoption("--browser")
    return _browser


@pytest.fixture()
def getDriver(request, getBrowser):
    global driver
    print("browser from getBrowser method - " + getBrowser)
    if getBrowser == "chrome":
        driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Tools\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe")

    driver.get(settings.url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    driver.maximize_window()
    request.cls.basePage = BasePage(driver)
    request.cls.loginPage = LoginPage(driver)
    request.cls.driver = driver
    # yield request.cls.driver
    yield driver
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.quit()
```

Functions from BasePage(as example):

```
class BasePage:
    def __int__(self,driver):
        self.driver = driver
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)

    def do_click(self, by_locator):
        # self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(by_locator)).click()
        self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(by_locator)).click()
```

Functions from LoginPage(as example):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from src.pom.pages.BasePage import BasePage


class LoginPage(BasePage):

    def __int__(self, driver):
        super().__int__(driver)
        self.driver = driver

    EMAIL = (By.ID, "login-email")
    PASSWORD = (By.ID, "login-password")
    LOGIN_BUTTON = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div [type='submit']")
    CAMPUS_LOGO = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".logo")
```

Eventually I get the error:

> ```
>   request.cls.basePage = BasePage(driver)
> ```

E       TypeError: BasePage() takes no arguments

I have tried to work with this structure of page object in python but I failed. I have expected to run tests that began to write.